# For Loop is giving stop script error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

```
(function ($) {
    // ***********************************************
    //The main fixedTable function
    $.fn.fixedTable = function (opts) {
        //default options defined in $.fn.fixedTable.defaults - at the bottom of this file.
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.fixedTable.defaults, opts);
        var mainid = "#" + options.outerId;
        var tbl = this;
        var layout = buildLayout(tbl, opts);
        //see the buildLayout() function below
        var fixedArea = $(".fixedArea").width() - 150;
        //alert($.fn.fixedTable.defaults);

        //we need to set the width (in pixels) for each of the tables in the fixedContainer area
        //but, we need to subtract the width of the fixedColumn area.
        var w = options.width - options.fixedColumnWidth;

        //sanity check
        if (w <= 0) { w = options.width; }
        //alert(options.width);
        $(".fixedContainer", layout).width(w);
        $(".fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader, layout).css({
            //width: (w) + "px",
            width: "100%",
            "float": "left",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        });
        $(".fixedContainer .fixedTable", layout).css({
            "float": "left",
            //width: (w + 8) + "px",
            width: "100%",
            "overflow": "auto"
        });
        $(".fixedContainer", layout).css({
            //width: w - 1,
            //width: "68%",
            "float": "left"
        });

        //adjust the main container to be just larger than the fixedTable
        $(".fixedContainer ." + options.classFooter, layout).css({
            width: (w) + "px",
            "float": "left",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        });
        $("." + options.classColumn + " > .fixedTable", layout).css({
            "width": options.fixedColumnWidth,
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "border-collapse": $(tbl).css("border-collapse"),
            "padding": "0"
        });

        $("." + options.classColumn, layout).width(options.fixedColumnWidth);
        $("." + options.classColumn, layout).height(options.height);
        $("." + options.classColumn + " ." + options.classHeader + " table tbody tr td", layout).width(options.fixedColumnWidth);
        $("." + options.classColumn + " ." + options.classFooter + " table tbody tr td", layout).width(options.fixedColumnWidth);

        //adjust the table widths in the fixedContainer area
        var fh = $(".fixedContainer > ." + options.classHeader + " > table", layout);
        var ft = $(".fixedContainer > .fixedTable > table", layout);
        var ff = $(".fixedContainer > ." + options.classFooter + " > table", layout);

        var maxWidth = fh.width();
        if (ft.length > 0 && ft.width() > maxWidth) { maxWidth = ft.width(); }
        if (ff.length > 0 && ff.width() > maxWidth) { maxWidth = ff.width(); }

        if (fh.length) { fh.width(maxWidth); }
        if (ft.length) { ft.width(maxWidth); }
        if (ff.length) { ff.width(maxWidth); }

        //adjust the widths of the fixedColumn header/footer to match the fixed columns themselves
        $("." + options.classColumn + " > ." + options.classHeader + " > table > tbody > tr:first > td", layout).each(function (pos) {
            var tblCell = $("." + options.classColumn + " > .fixedTable > table > tbody > tr:first > td:eq(" + pos + ")", layout);
            var tblFoot = $("." + options.classColumn + " > ." + options.classFooter + " > table > tbody > tr:first > td:eq(" + pos + ")", layout);
            var maxWidth = $(this).width();
            if (tblCell.width() > maxWidth) { maxWidth = tblCell.width(); }
            if (tblFoot.length && tblFoot.width() > maxWidth) { maxWidth = tblFoot.width(); }
            $(this).width(maxWidth);
            $(tblCell).width(maxWidth);
            if (tblFoot.length) { $(tblFoot).width(maxWidth); }
        });

        //set the height of the table area, minus the heights of the header/footer.
        // note: we need to do this after the other adjustments, otherwise these changes would be overwrote
        var h = options.height - parseInt($(".fixedContainer > ." + options.classHeader, layout).height()) - parseInt($(".fixedContainer > ." + options.classFooter, layout).height());
        var diff = $(".fixedArea").width() - options.fixedColumnWidth - w;
        var diffadd = $(".fixedContainer").width() + diff;
        $(".fixedContainer", layout).css("width", diffadd);

        // Fix Hight:Left and right Header table
        var leftTable = $(".fixedColumn .fixedHead table").height();
        var rightTable = $("#fixeddiv .fixedHead table").height();
        $(".fixedColumn .fixedHead table").height(rightTable);
        $("#fixeddiv .fixedHead table").height(rightTable);
        //sanity check
        if (h < 0) { h = options.height; }
        $(".fixedContainer > .fixedTable", layout).height(h);
        $("." + options.classColumn + " > .fixedTable", layout).height(h);
        //Adjust the fixed column area if we have a horizontal scrollbar on the main table
        // - specifically, make sure our fixedTable area matches the main table area minus the scrollbar height,
        //   and the fixed column footer area lines up with the main footer area (shift down by the scrollbar height)
        var tblWidth = $("#Open_Text_General").width();
        if (diffadd >= tblWidth) {
            var h = $(".fixedContainer > .fixedTable", layout)[0].offsetHeight;
        } else {
            var h = $(".fixedContainer > .fixedTable", layout)[0].offsetHeight - 17;
        }
        $("." + options.classColumn + " > .fixedTable", layout).height(h);  //make sure the row area of the fixed column matches the height of the main table, with the scrollbar

        // Apply the scroll handlers
        //$(".fixedContainer > .fixedTable", layout).scroll(function () {
        //handleScroll(mainid, options);
        //});

        //the handleScroll() method is defined near the bottom of this file.
        //$.fn.fixedTable.adjustSizes(mainid);
        adjustSizes(options);
        return tbl;
    }
    //function to support scrolling of title and first column
    fnScroll = function () {
        $('#divHeader').scrollLeft($('#table_div').scrollLeft());
        $('#firstcol').scrollTop($('#table_div').scrollTop());
    }
    function buildLayout(src, options) {
        //create a working area and add it just after our table.
        //The table will be moved into this working area
        var area = $("<div class=\"fixedArea\" style=\"float: left;width:100%;\"></div>").appendTo($(src).parent());

        //fixed column items
        var fc = $("<div class=\"" + options.classColumn + "\" style=\"float: left;\"></div>").appendTo(area);
        var fch = $("<div class=\"" + options.classHeader + "\"></div>").appendTo(fc);
        var fct = $("<div class=\"fixedTable\" id=\"firstcol\"></div>").appendTo(fc);
        var fcf = $("<div class=\"" + options.classFooter + "\"></div>").appendTo(fc);

        //fixed container items
        var fcn = $("<div class=\"fixedContainer\" id=\"fixeddiv\"></div>").appendTo(area);
        var fcnh = $("<div class=\"" + options.classHeader + "\" id=\"divHeader\"></div>").appendTo(fcn);
        var fcnt = $("<div class=\"fixedTable\" id=\"table_div\" style=\"position: relative; overflow: scroll\" onscroll=\"fnScroll()\"></div>").appendTo(fcn);
        var fcnf = $("<div class=\"" + options.classFooter + "\"></div>").appendTo(fcn);

        //create the fixed column area
        if (options.fixedColumns > 0 && !isNaN(options.fixedColumns)) {
            buildFixedColumns(src, "thead", options.fixedColumns, fch);
            buildFixedColumns(src, "tbody", options.fixedColumns, fct);
            buildFixedColumns(src, "tfoot", options.fixedColumns, fcf);
            //see the buildFixedColumns() function below
        }

        //Build header / footer areas
        buildFixedTable(src, "thead", fcnh);
        buildFixedTable(src, "tfoot", fcnf);
        //see the buildFixedTable() function below

        //Build the main table
        //we'll cheat here - the src table should only be a tbody section, with the remaining columns, 
        //so we'll just add it to the fixedContainer table area.
        fcnt.append(src);
        return area;
    }

    /* ******************************************************************** */
    // duplicate a table section (thead, tfoot, tbody), but only for the desired number of columns
    function buildFixedColumns(src, section, cols, target) {
        //TFOOT - get the needed columns from the table footer
        if ($(section, src).length) {
            var colHead = $("<table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" class=\"leftcol\"></table>").appendTo(target);

            //If we have a thead or tfoot, we're looking for "TH" elements, otherwise we're looking for "TD" elements
            var cellType = "td";  //deafault cell type
            if (section.toLowerCase() == "thead" || section.toLowerCase() == "tfoot") { cellType = "th"; }

            //check each of the rows in the thead
            $(section + " tr", src).each(function () {
                var tr = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(colHead);
                $(cellType + ":lt(" + cols + ")", this).each(function () {
                    $("<td>" + $(this).html() + "</td>").addClass(this.className).attr("id", this.id).appendTo(tr);
                    //Note, we copy the class names and ID from the original table cells in case there is any processing on them.
                    //However, if the class does anything with regards to the cell size or position, it could mess up the layout.
                    //Remove the item from our src table.
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
        }
    }

    /* ******************************************************************** */
    // duplicate a table section (thead, tfoot, tbody)
    function buildFixedTable(src, section, target) {
        if ($(section, src).length) {
            var th = $("<table width=\"100%\" id=\"addcols\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" align=\"left\" class=\"\"></table>").appendTo(target);
            var tr = null;

            //If we have a thead or tfoot, we're looking for "TH" elements, otherwise we're looking for "TD" elements
            var cellType = "td";  //deafault cell type
            if (section.toLowerCase() == "thead" || section.toLowerCase() == "tfoot") { cellType = "th"; }

            $(section + " tr", src).each(function () {
                var tr = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(th);
                $(cellType, this).each(function () {
                    $("<td class=\'header\'>" + $(this).html() + "</td>").appendTo(tr);
                });

            });
            //The header *should* be added to our head area now, so we can remove the table header
            $(section, src).remove();
        }
    }

    // ***********************************************
    // Handle the scroll events
    function handleScroll(mainid, options) {
        //Find the scrolling offsets
        var tblarea = $(mainid + " .fixedContainer > .fixedTable");
        var x = tblarea[0].scrollLeft;
        var y = tblarea[0].scrollTop;
        $(mainid + " ." + options.classColumn + " > .fixedTable")[0].scrollTop = y;
        $(mainid + " .fixedContainer > ." + options.classHeader)[0].scrollLeft = x;
        $(mainid + " .fixedContainer > ." + options.classFooter)[0].scrollLeft = x;
    }

    // ***********************************************
    //  Reset the heights of the rows in our fixedColumn area
    function adjustSizes(options) {
        var Id = options.outerId;
        var maintbheight = options.height;
        var backcolor = options.Contentbackcolor;
        var hovercolor = options.Contenthovercolor;
        var fixedColumnbackcolor = options.fixedColumnbackcolor;
        var fixedColumnhovercolor = options.fixedColumnhovercolor;
        // row height
        $("#" + Id + " ." + options.classColumn + " .fixedTable table tbody tr").each(function (i) {
            var maxh = 0;
            var fixedh = $(this).height();
            var contenth = $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table tbody tr").eq(i).height();
            if (contenth > fixedh) {
                maxh = contenth;
            }
            else {
                maxh = fixedh;
            }
            //$(this).height(contenth);
            $(this).children("td").height(maxh);
            $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table tbody tr").eq(i).children("td").height(maxh);
        });

        //adjust the cell widths so the header/footer and table cells line up
        var ccount = $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader + " table tr:first td").size();
        var widthArray = new Array();
        var totall = 0;

        $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader + " table tr:first td").each(function (pos) {
            var cwidth = $(this).width();
            $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table tbody td").each(function (i) {
                if (i % ccount == pos) {
                    if ($(this).width() > cwidth) {
                        cwidth = $(this).width();
                    }
                }
            });
            widthArray[pos] = cwidth;
            totall += (cwidth + 2);
        });
        var contentH = $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table").height();
        var addwidth = widthArray.length;
        var ww = addwidth * 3 + addwidth;
        if (contentH > 610) {
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) > 7) {
                var newwidth = $("#fixeddiv").width() - (17 + ww);
            } else {
                var newwidth = $("#fixeddiv").width() - 17;
            }
        } else {
            var newwidth = $("#fixeddiv").width();
        }
        //More column added 
        $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader + " table").width(newwidth);
        $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table").width(newwidth);
        var widthTdArray = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < widthArray.length; i++) {
            var headtdWd = $(this).width();
            $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader + " table tr td").each(function (j) {
                if (j % ccount == i) { headtdWd = $(this).width(); }
            }); // Get Header Section width value
            widthTdArray[i] = headtdWd;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < widthArray.length; i++) {
            $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader + " table tr:last td").each(function (j) {
                if (j % ccount == i) { // Fix width for Header section
                    $(this).css("width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    $(this).css("min-width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    $("#addcols table tr:last td span").css("width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) > 7) {
                        $("#fixeddiv table tr td span").css("width", (widthTdArray[i] - 3) + "px");
                    } else {
                        $("#fixeddiv table tr td span").css("min-width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    }
                    //if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) > 7 || $.browser.mozilla){
                    //  $("#addcols table tr:last td span").css("min-width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    //}
                }
            });
            $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table tr:nth-child(3) td").each(function (j) {
                if (j % ccount == i) { // Fix width for Content section
                    $(this).css("width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    $(this).css("min-width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    $("#fixeddiv table tr td span").css("width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) > 7) {
                        $("#fixeddiv table tr td span").css("width", (widthTdArray[i] - 3) + "px");
                    } else {
                        $("#fixeddiv table tr td span").css("min-width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    }
                    //if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) > 7 || $.browser.mozilla){
                    //  $("#fixeddiv table tr td span").css("min-width", widthTdArray[i] + "px");
                    //}                 
                }
            });
        }
        if (contentH > 610) {
            $("#fixeddiv .fixedHead table tr:first td:last").css("padding-left", 19);
            $("#fixeddiv .fixedHead table tr:last td:last").css("padding-left", 19);
        }

        // mouse in/out fixedColumn's fixedtable, change background color.
        $("#" + Id + " ." + options.classColumn + " .fixedTable table tr").each(function (i) {
            $(this).mouseover(function () {
                $(this).children("td").css({
                    "background-color": fixedColumnhovercolor
                });
                var obj = $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table tr").eq(i);
                obj.children("td").css({
                    "background-color": hovercolor
                });
                obj.children("td").children("pre").css({
                    "background-color": hovercolor
                });
            });
            $(this).mouseout(function () {
                $(this).children("td").css({
                    "background-color": fixedColumnbackcolor
                });
                var obj = $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table tr").eq(i);
                obj.children("td").css({
                    "background-color": backcolor
                });
                obj.children("td").children("pre").css({
                    "background-color": backcolor
                });
            });
        });

        // mouse in/out fixedContainer's fixedtable, change background color.
        $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table tr").each(function (i) {
            $(this).mouseover(function () {
                $(this).children("td").css({
                    "background-color": hovercolor
                });
                $(this).children("td").children("pre").css({
                    "background-color": hovercolor
                });
                var obj = $("#" + Id + " ." + options.classColumn + " .fixedTable table tr").eq(i);
                obj.children("td").css({
                    "background-color": fixedColumnhovercolor
                });

            });
            $(this).mouseout(function () {
                $(this).children("td").css({
                    "background-color": backcolor
                });
                $(this).children("td").children("pre").css({
                    "background-color": backcolor
                });
                var obj = $("#" + Id + " ." + options.classColumn + " .fixedTable table tr").eq(i);
                obj.children("td").css({
                    "background-color": fixedColumnbackcolor
                });
            });
        });

        var contenttbH = $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable table").height();

        if (contenttbH < maintbheight) {
            $("#" + Id + " ." + options.classColumn + " .fixedTable").height(contenttbH + 20);
            $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer .fixedTable").height(contenttbH + 20);
            $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader).width($("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader).width());
            $("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classFooter).width($("#" + Id + " .fixedContainer ." + options.classHeader).width());
        }
        else {
            //offset the footer by the height of the scrollbar so that it lines up right.
            $("#" + Id + " ." + options.classColumn + " > ." + options.classFooter).css({
                "position": "relative",
                "top": 16
            });
        }
        // Set .header class css style
        var header_bgcolor = $(".header").css("background-color");
        var color_head = $(".header").css("color");

        $(".fixedHead td").css("background-color", header_bgcolor);
        $(".fixedHead td").css("color", color_head);
        $(".fixedHead a").css("color", color_head);
    }
    window.onunload = null;

})(jQuery);
```

While executing above script i am getting error "stop this script" in IE 6 & IE 7, Line no 287 for loop is creating this error i think, please suggest me changes so i can fix this

****Can any one help me out to fix this please ?****

Comment: NOPE> Sorry. We read code. Not wall of code. tell where the exact problem is.

Comment: I'm not sure what's worse, posting more than 400 lines of code with no explanation and expecting people to fix a problem you *think* is somewhere, or not including the markup. No, in fact it's not much of a contest, it's the former.

Comment: Your problem is your excessive use of class selectors in jQuery. re-specify your selectors, ideally by ID or by tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"stop this script"** doesn't have to be the result of an error inside your script, it simply says that  your script is currently freezing the browser, because it takes to long to execute the instructions inside.

So you have to optimize the script. If you want us to help you to optimize the script you should provide the markup of the document or a demo, and a short description of the desired operations of the script.

Comment: I am having a problem similar to this , but my code is working fine on IE7 IE8 , it only has problem on IE9 , can you help me on this ?

Comment: Yes, but I need to see the script. You may open a new question for that.